# Passing variable over to a new HTTP Request

Tags: php, oop, http

As the title says, is there another way to pass a variable from "current" page over to "next" (new HTTP request) page without using sessions/cookies/$_GET?

Well, I guess $_POST could be an option too, but the thing here is, that I want to pass this variable from already executed $_POST back to *off-the-post* environment page, but inbetween I'm having a redirect, to disallow reposting the same form.

In other words, basicly, I'm trying to "make" a seamless PRG, but sessions/cookies/$_GET is not an option.

And yes, I'm working with classes (hence the `oop` tag). Therefore maybe some kind of magic functions, or *output control*?

This has to work within PHP environment, no JavaScript or other non server side language.

I also have a bad feeling that it's impossible, but hopefully I'm wrong, and there is a solution.

Thanks in advance!

## update no. 1

Basicly, I want to create a PRG with response.

Inside this $_POST I'm adding data to database. I want this response to hold information whether this database query has been successful or not. Kind of make this $_POST process almost invisible to the user. And yes, display a response with the result later on.

All of this happens in one method:

```
if($_POST){
    // insertion
}else{
    // display no-post environment, if response exists (therefore posted) display response too
}
```

Something like that...

Sessions is not an option because this is meant to be some kind of API.

## update no. 2

Huh, let me rephrase the question a little. Well, it seems that I don't actually need to pass the variable over. What I want to do, is to have 2 different results after POST so on next page load I could know whether the actions in POST has been successful or not. So, what other options are out there without using sessions/cookies/$_GET to get this result?

Currently there is:

- temporary database usage: a good option, but I'd like to see different options;

Comment: What do you need this for? Maybe there's another way to do what you need. anyway, it's definitely not related to OOP - whether you're using classes or not shouldn't make a difference. How about adding `http` as a tag instead?

Comment: are you trying to send data to 2 scripts at the same time? is that correct?

Comment: Why are sessions not an option?

Comment: @Pekka, I added the OOP tag, because I'm thinking it could be done with http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php and I think those are not available out of classes, therefore OOP. About usage, see updated question.

Comment: Ah yes, wasn't edited at the time I posted the comment, edited now.

Comment: You can't do a POST for a redirect, so you've eliminated the only three methods for passing things between two otherwise seperate pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using a database it seems like the easiest way to handle this would be to update some kind of temporary table with the information you want based on the post call, then on the page you're doing a header redirect to, read the information in that table.  With the constraints you've placed on this (no GET, SESSION, Cookie or Javascript) you're not going to be able to maintain a variable when you redirect from one page to the next.

So leverage that database and take the work off of PHP.  Initially I was going to suggest utilizing cURL but I don't think that will help here (though you may want to look it up if you're unfamiliar with it, as it might be what you're looking for)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP [is a stateless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol); thus, there's not going to be an easy, built-in way to add state. That said, I think sessions are the best way to accomplish what you want to do. If what you're doing isn't in the browser, maybe try some sort of session key setup (like the Facebook platform uses).